# Mars Assembly not opening

Tags: assembly, installation, mars-simulator

So I tried to install Mars IDE but when I double click it, it wont open. I reinstalled Java and Mars multiple times but it just wont work. Also restarted computer. Anyone knows solution?

Comment: Run it from a command window. You may get some error message then.

Comment: java -jar MARS4_5.jar